# change style of numeric numbers in a text by css

Tags: css

I have a text like (03 Days 02 Night Package, Starts from $120). Is there anyway I can change the style of the numbers using only css. I know I can do this by adding an extra html tag or using jquery. Have been looking for this quite a time now but can't find anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, it is not possible

Answer (score 7):

It is not possible, using pure CSS, to target only digits in a text.

The only thing you can do is [change the font family](//stackoverflow.com/a/40088765/962603) of digits only.

This uses the `unicode-range` ([spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-css-fonts-3-20131003/#unicode-range-desc), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range)) directive. When using fonts from Google Fonts, it [can be used as follows](//stackoverflow.com/a/32488134/962603). I have selected the digits and dollar sign here, but any range of characters can be selected in the `text` parameter.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&text=0123456789$');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ranga');

p {
  font-family: 'Raleway', 'Ranga', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<p>03 Days 02 Night Package, Starts from $120</p>
```

---

Because you only mention extra HTML tags and jQuery in your answer, I thought that it might be helpful to show you how to do it in vanilla JavaScript.

```js
let elementToFindDigitsIn = document.querySelector('p');
elementToFindDigitsIn.innerHTML =
    elementToFindDigitsIn
      .textContent
      .replace(/(\$?\d+)/g, '<span>$1</span>');
```

```css
span {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>03 Days 02 Night Package, Starts from $120</p>
```

Indeed, as mentioned by [@LGSon](//stackoverflow.com/users/2827823/lgson) in a comment, it is also possible to give different classes to different numbers quite easily, this way.

```js
let elementToFindDigitsIn = document.querySelector('p'),
    count = 0;
elementToFindDigitsIn.innerHTML =
    elementToFindDigitsIn
      .textContent
      .replace(/(\$?\d+)/g, (s) => {
        let c = `num-${++count}`;
        if (s[0] === '$') {
          c += ' money';
        }
        return `<span class="${c}">${s}</span>`;
      });
```

```css
span {
  color: blue;
}

span.money {
  color: red;
}

span.num-2 {
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<p>03 Days 02 Night Package, Starts from $120</p>
```

Comment: Nice and simple, plus 1, (even if script is not wanted), and if you through in a counter in that regex, you could set a class and color them one by one `"<span class='colnr" + (++count) + "'>" + x + "</span>"` ... https://jsfiddle.net/n37rr4fx/

Comment: Didn't know about range in fonts import  .. Nice !

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code if you want to add similar color in a aal numbers that is available in your text.

```html
<style>
 p span{
   color:red;
}

</style>

<p><span>03</span> Days <span>02</span> Night Package, Starts from <span>$120</span></p>
```

But If you want to add different color then you can add this css and html in your file.

```html
<style>
     p span:nth-child(1){
       color:red;
    }
    p span:nth-child(2){
       color:green;
    }
    p span:nth-child(3){
       color:purple;
    }
    

    </style>

    <p><span>03</span> Days <span>02</span> Night Package, Starts from <span>$120</span></p>
```

I hope it will helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks roopa, but I don't want to add any extra html tags. and targetting only numbers using css not possible which @LGSon already said.

Comment: ya actually we can't track only perticular letters or numbers in a single text paragraph or in any bunch of text.